# Are pure or modified sine inverters different?

Tags: electricity

Just starting my power closet to power my off grid mobile home
I've come to question everyone that I belive would know with no concrete answer
Is there a difference between using a modified sine or pure sine inverter?

Comment: Sounds like a better question for https://electronics.stackexchange.com

Comment: @Jan Doggen you are correct. I did a quick search on said stackexchange with search string 'modified sine wave inverter' and came up with quite a lot of info.

Answer (score 1):

> Both types of inverter will provide power to AC appliances, however Pure Sine is high quality equal to (or better than) the power in your home, Modified sine wave power is an simpler form of power and is adequate for simple electronics, but may damage more complex ones.

Source: https://www.baintech.com.au/what-is-the-difference-between-a-pure-sine-and-modified-sine-inverter